# How does one provide content for Chromecast backdrop

Tags: chromecast

Chromecast supports the notion of a "backdrop" for showing images while in idle mode.  It has a few sources such as Facebook, Google Photos, etc.

Is there an API or something to add a new source of imagery to this?

Thanks!

Comment: Googling "Chromecast API" found the cast API site:  [https://developers.google.com/cast/?hl=en](https://developers.google.com/cast/?hl=en)

Comment: Unfortunately there does not appear to be anything about the backdrop mode in the API.  Hence the question.

Comment: If it's not listed in the API reference, I'd assume that it's not possible then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no API to add a new source for the backdrop.

Comment: Thanks.  Is there a request form or something for companies that would like to make our content available on the platform?  I run Product for DeviantArt.com and would love to get our content on the platform.

Comment: Please ask on our G+ Cast Developer Community (http://goo.gl/TPLDxj) and I'll try to get someone respond there.